# how do i create a login flow for my website?

Tags: rest, http, authentication, web, websocket

Basically I've implemented a WebSocket server with a connected Mongodb as a database. After my server receives username-password from client, it expects to receive messages which are to be saved in the database. Problem arises here as how do I verify that the client is still logged in or maybe how do I even know if the messages are coming from the correct source?

I've had a look at OAuth and OpenId Connect but they seem to be tools for a different use, any further info as in which domain my question falls and suggested readings or books will be helpful.

Comment: The credentials are sent with "every" HTTP request in the authorization header field. See here (sec 14.8): http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html You read them and authenticate/authorize client on each request.

Comment: That would be true for HTTP, but WebSocket is not HTTP. It happens to use HTTP to initiate the WebSocket connection (you can use HTTP authentication as part of that process), but once the connection has been established, there is no need to send credentials anymore, the connection is persistent until one of the parties closes it.